# How to keep php $_GET value from a submit button after form submit from javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, get, form-submit

I have a php page with 2 submit buttons and 2 radio buttons:

```
<?php
$choiceIdx = 1;
$language = 'English';

if($_GET)
{
    if(isset( $_GET['choice'] ))
    {
        $choiceIdx = $_GET['choice'];
    }
    if(isset( $_GET['language'] ))
    {
        $language = $_GET['language'];
    }
}
?>

<form method="get">
    <button type='submit' name='choice' value='1'>Choice1</button>
    <button type='submit' name='choice' value='2'>Choice2</button>

    <input id="English" type="radio" name="language" value="English" <?php echo ($language=='English')?'checked':'' ?> onchange="this.form.submit();" />
    <label for="English">English</label>

    <input id="Slovenian" type="radio" name="language" value="Slovenian" <?php echo ($language=='Slovenian')?'checked':'' ?> onchange="this.form.submit();" />
    <label for="Slovenian">Slovenian</label>
</form>
```

If I click on Slovenian radio button, I get:

```
http://localhost/index.php?language=Slovenian
```

If I then click on Choice2 submit button, "language" is saved and I get:

```
http://localhost/index.php?choice=2&language=Slovenian
```

If I then click on English radio button, "choice" is not saved and I get:

```
http://localhost/index.php?language=English
```

This is my first php page and after hours of googling i added this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="choice" value="<?php echo $choiceIdx; ?>">
```

The "choice" is now saved, but i get:

```
http://localhost/index.php?choice=1&language=Slovenian&choice=2
```

I don't want it twice in url. Please explain what i am doing wrong. Thank you!

EDIT: I want to use GET (and not POST) because the URL has to be saved as a bookmark.

Comment: Just use POST instead of GET. I.e. it can't be in the url twice if its not in the url once.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, POST would not fix this. You need to find a new way to save the choice, because whichever button you click to submit will submit the value of that button (you've named the buttons 'choice') and your hidden input choice will always be sent...so yeah, you will get two choice parameters.

Comment: Maybe make the choice option a dropdown rather than two buttons.

Comment: @developerwjk this is just an short example - the real page generates a varying number of buttons with php code. a dropdown is not an option as i have to follow a design made by the designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternate version (as a followup to my first answer) that updates the hidden value when clicking the choice-button:

```
<script>
function setChoice(val) {
    document.getElementById('hiddenChoice').value=val;
}
</script>

<form method="get">
    <button type='submit' onClick="setChoice(1);">Choice1</button>
    <button type='submit' onClick="setChoice(2);">Choice2</button>
    <input type='hidden' id='hiddenChoice' name='choice' value='<?php echo $choiceIdx; ?>'>
    <input id="English" type="radio" name="language" value="English" <?php echo ($language=='English')?'checked':'' ?> onchange="this.form.submit();" />
    <label for="English">English</label>

    <input id="Slovenian" type="radio" name="language" value="Slovenian" <?php echo ($language=='Slovenian')?'checked':'' ?> onchange="this.form.submit();" />
    <label for="Slovenian">Slovenian</label>
</form>
```

If you have more values to retrieve you might want to create a more sofisticated and less specific js-function. You could easily pass in the id of the target input f.e.

Also you should rethink if it's realy neccessary to *always* submit the form, or if it might be better to first collect all the data and only send one form back to the server.

Comment: Thanks! I always have to submit a form - i am making a tree structure where you start at the root of the tree and pick a choice and submit it to delete the current nodes/choices and display the child nodes/choices of the chosen parent node/choice.

Answer (score 0):

Add that to your form:

```
 <input type='hidden' name='choiceStored' value='<?php echo $choiceIdx; ?>'>
```

This will store the last received val for choice and re-send it at the next form submit.

and change your php to:

```
$choiceIdx = 1;
$language = 'English';

if($_GET)
{
    // eighter get new value
    if(isset( $_GET['choice'] ))
    {
        $choiceIdx = $_GET['choice'];

      // or if we don't have a new value, take the 'stored' one:
    } elseif (isset($_GET['choiceStored'])) 
    {
        $choiceIdx = $_GET['choiceStored'];
    }

    if(isset( $_GET['language'] ))
    {
        $language = $_GET['language'];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you read my question carefully you will see that this is exactly what i added after many hours of googling - but it creates a bad url.

Comment: now i get: index.php?choiceStored=1&language=Slovenian&choice=2 - the reason i don't want this is that i want the bookmarked url to work unambiguously

Comment: this will also work as a bookmark! (although choiceStored is obsolet in that example). If you still don't like it you'd have to write a javascript-function that does the form-submit and first collects the desired values.

Comment: thanks! <input id="choice" type='hidden' name='choice' value='<?php echo $choiceIdx; ?>'> and <button type='submit' onclick="document.getElementById('choice').value = 1;">Choice</button> works like a charm :) if you change your answer i will upvote and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the same name twice. 'choice' has been defined as both the hidden value name and the button value name. To be able to differentiate, you should change the hidden value name to something like 'savedchoice'. And reference it by that name